# Get FCM Token from Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to store user's FCM tokens in a firebase document so I can push notifications for that specific device.

My question: what's the best way to get the FCM token from Unity?

I tried to get the token with following script:

```
public class FCM : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += TokenReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
    }

    private void MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Message received: " + e.Message);
    }

    private void TokenReceived(object sender, TokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Token received: "+ e.Token);
        text.text = "received a token";
    }
}
```

The method TokenReceived never gets triggered on my android device.

Comment: Have you completed [FCM setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client) to ensure you have access to the token?

Comment: hey; yeah i followed that guide and i am able to receive notification by pushing a notification via firebase console. I am still not a sure how to get the registration token from unity tho.

Comment: the thing is: as mentioned i am getting notification when i push them with firebase console but i dont get any token, in other words my callback function TokenReceived(object sender, TokenReceivedEventArgs e) doesnt get triggered on my android device.

Comment: Are you using a custom UnityPlayerActivity or the default generated one?

Comment: @AndrewH i am using the default one

Comment: I wasn't able to find much in the way of existing solutions online, but [maybe Play Services is outdated](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/74)?